# macos swiftui - add menu item inside window menu

Tags: swiftui, menuitem

I need to add a menu item at the place where for example XCode place's the "Window" -> "Developers Documentation" menu item is available.
This Menu Item needs a short cut and a checkmark if the window is open.
Also the menu Item should close the window when chosen again.

For now I use.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

@main
struct Navigate_DetailApp: App {

@StateObject var listItemsViewModel : ItemModelView = ItemModelView()
@StateObject var appState = AppState()
@State var isProductWindowOpen = false

let someWindow = NSWindow( contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 380, height: 300), styleMask: [.titled, .closable],  backing: .buffered, defer: false)


var body: some Scene {

    WindowGroup ("New") {
        ContentView(appState: appState)
            .frame(minWidth: 800, maxWidth: 900, minHeight: 500, maxHeight: 600)
            .environmentObject(listItemsViewModel)
    }

   WindowGroup("Products") {
            ProductsView()
        }
        Toggle("Products-toggle", isOn: $isProductWindowOpen)
                .onChange(of: isProductWindowOpen) { ison in
                    print("isON")
                    if ison {
                        print("open")
                        someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
                        someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                    } else {
                        print("close")
                        someWindow.close()
                    }
                }                               
            .keyboardShortcut("0")
            Button("Products-but open") {
                //OpenWindows.ProductsView.open()
                print("Menu Button Open")
                someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
                someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("1")
            Button("Products-but close") {
                print("Menu Button Close")
                someWindow.close()
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("2")

            Button("Products-but open/") {
                print("Menu Button OpenClose Toggle")
                isProductWindowOpen.toggle()
                if isProductWindowOpen == true {
                    print("open")
                    someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
                    someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                } else {
                    print("close")
                    someWindow.close()
                }
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("3")

.... OLD CODE
    func openProductsWindow() {
        someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
        self.someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
    func closeProductsWindow() {
        .... ?? how to close the window
    }

....

struct ProductsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Products")
            .frame(minWidth: 600, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400)
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to accomplish the  placement of the menu item and let it close the window.

EDIT =================

Again thank you, it clarifies some issue's. Unfortunate it doesn't work. Did change some code to try to get it working but same effect; nothings happens. Looking with the debugger, it never comes to the action or print statement.

With the added Buttons and their code it works, for only one time. Meaning if I use the 'button open' it opens the ProductsView, if I use 'Button Close', it closes the window, but then it doesn't open it any more, however it shows the print statement in the debugger.
What can I do to get both working, the Toggle and multiply using the Buttons ( No Checkmark ) ?

With the Button and then let it toggle, it works also only one time. Open and Close, but then its over, no more open or close window. The debugger shows:

```
Menu Button OpenClose Toggle
open
Menu Button OpenClose Toggle
close
Menu Button OpenClose Toggle
open
Menu Button OpenClose Toggle
open
Menu Button OpenClose Toggle
close
```

=========

Step Forward - New Code that works, but..

I did move the State to a StateObject blah blah, and that works okay, I show the code. But why does your code works for you but not for me?

```
@main
struct menuItemInsertWindowApp: App {

    @StateObject var productMenuState = MenuState()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        WindowGroup("Products") {
            ProductsView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .windowList) {
                ProductMenuItem(productMenuState: productMenuState)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ContentView")
            .frame(minWidth: 600, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400)
    }
}

struct ProductsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Products")
            .frame(minWidth: 500, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 300, maxHeight: 400)
    }
}

class MenuState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isProductWindowOpen = false
}

struct ProductMenuItem : View {
    let someWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 400), styleMask: [.titled, .closable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)

    @ObservedObject var productMenuState : MenuState

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Products - Toggle That Works", isOn: $productMenuState.isProductWindowOpen)
            .onChange(of: productMenuState.isProductWindowOpen) { value in
                print( "change isProductWindowOpen" )
                if value {
                    print( "ProductWindow Opens" )
                    someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
                    someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                } else {
                    print( "ProductWindow Closes" )
                    someWindow.close()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

It Works however if you look at the XCode log it shows some strange double called line's. Is this because of a macOS bug or XCode compiling bug or....
Is this solvable?

```
change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Opens
change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Opens

change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Closes
change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Closes
change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Closes

onChange(of: Bool) action tried to update multiple times per frame.
onChange(of: Bool) action tried to update multiple times per frame.

change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Opens
change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Opens

onChange(of: Bool) action tried to update multiple times per frame.
onChange(of: Bool) action tried to update multiple times per frame.
onChange(of: Bool) action tried to update multiple times per frame.

change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Closes
change isProductWindowOpen
ProductWindow Closes
```

Also later, duplicate windows of the window shows up, as well when I rapidly pressing the shortkeys.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

to "...add menu item inside window menu", you could try this approach:

```
        CommandGroup(replacing: .windowList) {
            Button("Products") {
                print("----> clicked Products")
            }
        }
```

EDIT-1: given your new code, you could also try this, or something similar (adjust according to your needs):

```
        CommandGroup(replacing: .windowList) {
            Toggle("Products", isOn: $isProductWindowOpen)
                .onChange(of: isProductWindowOpen) { ison in
                    if ison {
                        someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
                        someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                    } else {
                        someWindow.close()
                    }
                }
        }
```

EDIT-2: this is the test code that works well for me.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    let someWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 400), styleMask: [.titled, .closable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    
    @State var isProductWindowOpen = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        WindowGroup("Products") {
            ProductsView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .windowList) {
                Button("Products open") {
                    print("Products Button Open")
                    someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
                    someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                } .keyboardShortcut("1")
                
                Button("Products close") {
                    print("Products Button Close")
                    someWindow.close()
                }.keyboardShortcut("2")
                
                Button("Products toggle") {
                    print("Products toggle")
                    isProductWindowOpen.toggle()
                    if isProductWindowOpen {
                        print("open")
                        someWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ProductsView())
                        someWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
                    } else {
                        print("close")
                        someWindow.close()
                    }
                }.keyboardShortcut("3")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ProductsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Products")
            .frame(minWidth: 600, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ContentView")
            .frame(minWidth: 600, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 400, maxHeight: 400)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I did update the code, because I can't get it to work. Please can you give it a look what I do wrong or doesn't understand.

Comment: updated my answer with more sample code. That code works well for me, that is, it opens, closes and toggles the `ProductsView` window from the `Window` menu.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time. Doesn't work for me. Did create a new project; copied your code but got the same behaviour as before. Toggle doesn't work. The buttons do only one time. - 
I am using a MBP Retina 2015 with macOS 12.5 and XCode Version 13.4.1 (13F100) with XCode 12 compatible format.

Comment: workingdog support Ukraine :  I did get it to work - See my question updated. Do you know why this happens.

Comment: Don't know why you have those warnings.
Try using, `@State var isProductWindowOpen` like you used to, instead of the `class MenuState : ObservableObject`, 
since that works in my code. Pass it to the `ProductMenuItem` as a binding.

Comment: Also later, duplicate windows of the window shows up, as well when I rapidly pressing the shortkeys.